# How do I format a date in a string variable to year date month in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a date in string variable `strOrderEndDate` which looks like this 8/14/2015.
I would like to convert it to 2015-08-14. 
How do I do this in vb.net?

I tried `strOrderEndDate.ToString(yyyy mmmm dd)` but its not working

Comment: like you said, you have a **STRING**. first you have to convert that to a native date/time value/object. just because something LOOKS like a date to you doesn't mean VB will magically understand that it's a date.

Comment: Date format codes mean nothing to string variables, and "mmmm" wont mean anything.  Convert to a DateTime type and use `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` .  [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) are all fully documented. ...and dont use `CDate` to convert - learn to use `DateTime.Parse` methods

Comment: When I did this `strOrderEndDate.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy")` I got this error `Option Strict on disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to  'System.IFormatProvider' `

Comment: you skipped the first step: convert/parse to a `DateTime` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate, you first need to convert the string to a date using `CDate`.  Then you can use the `.ToString` method on the new date type variable to format the output as desired:

```
 Dim strOrderEndDate As String = "8/14/2015"
 Dim datOrderEndDate As Date = CDate(strOrderEndDate)
 MsgBox(datOrderEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

...or as Plutonix recommends, you can use `DateTime.Parse` to perform the conversion.  He's pretty smart so if he says it's better, then it's better.

```
 Dim datOrderEndDate As Date = DateTime.Parse(strOrderEndDate)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. This is what I did `strOrderEndDate = CDate(strOrderEndDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`